# VueJS - Ajax communication between templates

Tags: vue.js

I'm very new to VueJS and i'm having a difficult to share a result from Two template, that come from AJAX Request.

This is the home page:

```
<div>
   <search-bar></search-bar>
   <tracking-results></tracking-results>
</div>
```

This is the search-bar component, where i have a text input field and after press the button, it will do an Ajax Request:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-3">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero Spedizione" v-model="trackingNumber">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default"
                            type="button"
                            @click.prevent="search">Ricerca</button>
                  </span>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                trackingNumber: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            search() {
                Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true;

                this.$http.post('/endpoint').then(function (response) {
                    var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.data) || undefined;
                    /* HERE I WANT TO SEND THE RESPONSE TO ANOTHER COMPONENT */
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log('ERROR', err);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I did tried with `$broadcast`, but my components arent child, are sibling.

I did see a way can be Vuex, but my application will not be written entirely with Vue. I will use this framework just to "simplify some Javascript process".

The only alternative i did find is to "merge" the `search-bar` and `tracking-result` in a single component. In this way the data will be "shared", and i can communicate with the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update: [`sync` is removed in Vue 2](https://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#once-and-sync-Modifiers-on-v-bind-removed), so you would need to follow the standard [props-down, events-up design pattern]](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)

You can have the parent viewmodel pass a prop to each of the components, [using `sync`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Prop-Binding-Types) for the search bar. The search bar would populate the value in the ajax call, it would sync up to the parent and down to the tracking-results.

Some example code:

```js
Vue.component('child1', {
  props: ['ajaxData'],
  methods: {
    loadData: function () {
      this.ajaxData = 'Some data is loaded';
    }
  },
  template: '<div>Child1: {{ajaxData}} <button v-on:click="loadData">Load data</button></div>'
});
Vue.component('child2', {
  props: ['ajaxData'],
  template: '<div>Child2: {{ajaxData}}</div>'
});
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    hi: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<child1 :ajax-data.sync='hi'></child1>
<child2 :ajax-data='hi'></child2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you can send data to the parent, then the parent send data to the component via props. The parent handles the communication between the siblings.

Another way of doing it is using state management or vuex. But that depends on the complexity of your project. If it's a simple thing, I suggest to let the parent handle the communication.

Comment: Because i will use Vue with Laravel, i dont know if Vuex will be a valid option. Not because Vuex is not valid (the Flux architecture is wonderful, and i come from Redux). But... if i will use Vuex i have to handle all the state of my application with it, or i can "mix", and so use vuex for just some parts ?

Comment: You probably don't even need vuex here.

For me here

```
<div>
   <search-bar></search-bar> //child-1
   <tracking-results></tracking-results> //child-2
</div>

```

The file containing these two is the `parent`. Right?

So, dispatch your data from child-1 to parent, the send by props to child-2.

Comment: In this way, every time i have to share properties between components i have first to go parent and later go down to childs ?

Comment: Yes that's I meant!